# How do I rotate individual bones in XNA in a model?

Tags: matrix, xna, rotation, blender

I'm making a game in XNA that is a shooting role-plaing game. I have made a human model in Blender and imported it into XNA. I loaded it and can rotate the entire model, but how do I rotate each bone? I tried looking this up on google, but found no good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the simple animation sample in the education section:  http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/simple_animation

I know it can seem complicated at first, but you really have to stick it with it until you groc it, there isn't too many shortcuts to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ChangeBoneTransform(int boneIndex, Matrix t)
    {
        model.Bones[boneIndex].Transform = t * model.Bones[boneIndex].Transform ;
    }
```

Make sure you copy AbsoluteBoneTransforms each time you draw your model

That's it

To rotate use :-
ChangeBoneTransform(1, Matrix.CreateRotationX(0.1f)); //in the Update() Method